# Auth capability with Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-server

I am trying to figure out how to authenticate with a Selenium server instance.

I have this:

```
let webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('firefox')
  .withCapabilities(xxx)
  .usingServer('http://seleniumbox.wisco.com/wd/hub')
  .build();
```

I believe I have to set a username/password as a capability. But I do not know how to create a new Capability instance with Node.js.

Here are the docs, I am trying to find an example, but cannot find anything:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/

I believe I need to pass the auth information as `xxx` above, but don't have an example.

Without any auth information, I get this error:

```
   SessionNotCreatedError: Error forwarding the new session :Mandatory capability missing[auth]
       at WebDriverError (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/wisco/cdt-now/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
       at SessionNotCreatedError (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/wisco/cdt-now/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:214:5)
       at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/wisco/cdt-now/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:517:15)
       at parseHttpResponse (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/wisco/cdt-now/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
       at doSend.then.response (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/wisco/cdt-now/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
```